# If a Chrome extension crashes, how do I make another extension reload the crashed extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't seem to find a way to do this. Any idea how?

Comment: There is no way to do this. All extensions are self-contained HTML and Javascript.

Comment: If the plugin hasn't crashed, I can make another extension disable it, then re-enable it to the effect of "reloading" it, but when the plugin has crashed, enabling doesn't work. This would be nice to have.

Comment: I can see that you are making an extension that will automatically re-enable crashed extensions.

Comment: @Derek That's indeed that case... But it's for private use. :D

Comment: @trusktr - You can disable or enable extensions, but you can't know when does it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable or disable an extension, but it is not possible to know when it crashes.

```
var id = "afhufhsauofhgshoughueghoegr",
    enable = true;
chrome.management.setEnabled(id, enable, function(){
    alert("Enabled.")
})
```

with the permission `management`.

```
"permissions": [
  "management"
]
```

---

You might try, but I don't know if this will also work for crashing:

```
chrome.management.onDisabled.addListener
```

---

For more information, see the [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html).

Comment: I tried using chrome.management.setEnabled() with the crashed extension's id but that causes an error complaining that the extension can't be found. I am able to detect when the extension crashes though...

Comment: @trusktr  If it is not listed, then you can do nothing about it unless you use a [NPAPI plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html).

Comment: I added an issue to Chromium: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131977&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: @trusktr - I don't think that is a bug though... You should ask it here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/chromium-extensions

Comment: The problem with Groups is that I'll receive updates on each and every single discussion thread in order to just be updated on one issue... As a result of that, I've decided never to use Groups. Is there some way to receive updates on only one thread that I've missed somehow?

Comment: Of course you can. But I can't teach you how because it displays in Chinese in my browser sorry

Comment: Alright, I'll test it out and see if I won't receive messages from all the threads. I think it'd be a nice feature to be able to re-enable crashed extensions with `chrome.management.setEnabled()` though. What do you think?

Comment: @trusktr - IMO it is *kind of* a nice feature. Why? Because it is not-so-useful in many cases. Why would they create a method for only a specific group of extensions?

Comment: Well it's not a new method, it's one that already exists and it'd seem logical that doing .setEnabled(id, true) using the id of a crashed extension should reload it. Know what I mean? I've written an extension that monitors a second extension and I need this for crash handling so the first extension (the controller) can reload the second (controlled) extension if it crashes. The purpose for this is so that the  monitoring extension can keep track of state, while the second extension reflects the state and can be restored if media crashes it.

Comment: I get your point. :) And do you remember the question "how to crash the browser"? I tried the script in IE, and it crashed my computer.

Comment: Haha that's funny. Good thing I'm writing this for Chrome only. hehe